# Old jquery build and .ajax()

Tags: jquery

I'm working to renew some old site that uses very old jquery (for example, it does not know what the ".html()" method is. It uses .update() instead of this). When i replace the old library with a new one (the last is jQuery 3.4.0) - all site's jquery functionality crashes... But i need to use .ajax (instead of the old ajax.request() ) to be able to get data from other site. If i leave the old library - i got "Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function" in console, but if i place the old library and the latest one - all site's old-jquery functionality crashes, but .ajax() works good.

So, how can i get a custom (only ajax) build (something like jQuery 3.4.0 slim build) of the latest release, but just with the implenemtation of the .ajax() function, to use only ajax() from te latest release ( jQuery 3.4.0) ?

And old-fashion code like

```
new Ajax.Request('delivery.html?ajax=payment&DeliveryId=' + value + '&mdaa=' + mdaa_ev.value + '&api_delivery_price=' + api_delivery_price.value, {
  method: 'get',
  onSuccess: function(transport) {
    $('PaymentsProcess').hide();
    $('Payments').innerHTML = transport.responseText;

    var paymentId = 0;
    $('frmOrder').getInputs('radio', 'PaymentId').each(function(el) {
      if (el.checked) paymentId = el.value;
    });
    if (paymentId) setPayment(paymentId);
  }
});
```

cannot reach the other site because of CORS headers problems... I have to use something like this:

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      url: 'https://e-solution.pickpoint.ru/api/login',
      dataType: 'json',
      crossDomain: true,
      data: data1,
      success: function(data) {
          ........
```

but it does not work with old jquery biuld... So i need custom ajax jquery build to mix old site's code and the new . ajax() ))))

Tnx.

Comment: I've tried to re-build jquery using Node.js and 

$ jquery-builder --exclude effects > outputfile.js

but nothing helps...

Comment: Maybe just use a different Ajax Library instead? Like axios or something. Then there's no conflict

Comment: Great tnx. it helps! SOLVED!